# Help understanding the behavior of an RLC circuit

Tags: simulation

I am trying to generate a transient pulse (time to peak T1 = 6us; time to fall to 50% of peak T2 = 70us)  with an RLC circuit. The cap is first charged and then discharged through an LR circuit. I noticed that T1 increases when L1 is increased, and T2 increases when I increase R1. Why is that? Are T1 and T2 independent of each other? I expected T1 and T2 to both increase as I increment either R1 or L1. Is the time constant governed by RL or the RC circuit? Finally, how do I "soothen" out the waveform so it doesn't have those sharp turns as seen in pic 2. 
[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]

Comment: What is the ultimate use for the transient pulse itself? I ask because, depending on this, you may have different pulse generation choices besides RC+LC, for example: RC+RC or avalanche BJT. Can you share with us some details? What is the shape you are expecting to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In your simulation the values are somewhat independent, since you control switch ramp time dt=11us. in the model .

The L/R =T= 1.5uH/0.6 = 2.5us would be dominant if it had a <1us time switch.

Fall time is usually calculated from 90 to 10% , which is longer than PW50  which is longer than T(100-50%).

T2 is dominated by R1C2=0.6*168uF= 100us.  Since 90-10%=80% , the T50% duration will be approx. 5/8*100us=63us, as a 1st approximation again determined by R1C2.

The zoomed simulation area needs more timebase resolution in your setup,as there is interpolation noise.  Unless you include stray capacitance on the switch and Rs for the capacitor and other factors, you can't expect more accuracy.

Is this an air core inductor? You might want to model the physical model for EMI stray effects with 16kA.!!